# Is it possible to clone a USB on windows IoT via UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, usb, clone, windows-10-iot-core

I'm relatively new to C# and programming in general, so please bear with me. I'm working on a UWP app using an Upboard with Windows IoT. I need to clone an image to a USB device, but I'm facing permission issues with USB access.

I have already added BroadFileSystemAccess capability and managed to launch executable files using ProcessLauncher (FullTrustLauncher didn't work). I then tried using a Python script converted to an executable, but it resulted in an error regarding USB permissions. I also tried creating a PowerShell executable, but it seems I'm missing some required modules.

Is there something else I can try? Should I just wait till we get a proper windows license?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can refer to the [official sample Removable storage sample](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/msdn-code-gallery-microsoft/blob/master/Official%20Windows%20Platform%20Sample/Windows%208.1%20Store%20app%20samples/%5BC%23%5D-Windows%208.1%20Store%20app%20samples/Removable%20storage%20sample/C%23/S2_SendToStorage.xaml.cs#L112). After setting the `BroadFileSystemAccess` capability, do you open the file permission in the App settings?